# How does a stake pool node certify a block for the block chain?

Tags: stake-pool

How does a stake pool node certify a block for the blockchain? What part is done manually by a human pool operator and what part is done by a machine through automation?

Say Peter pays Paul $10 ADA. A pool is selected to process that transaction. What happens next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cardano, time is segmented into 5 day *epochs* and 1 second *slots*.

As users publish transactions on the network, pools distribute the transactions to their peers and store valid transactions locally in a queue, known as the *mempool*.

In each *slot*, one or more *validators* (pools) may be selected to forge a block. That block will contain transactions from the mempool, up to max block size.

Validators are able to independently check if they are elected as the slot leader. From the [Ourobouros Praos paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/573.pdf):

> only a slot leader is aware that it is indeed a leader for a given slot; this assignment is unknown to all the other stakeholders—including other slot leaders of the same slot—until the other stakeholders receive a valid block from this slot leader

Blocks are signed by a validator with their *operational key* and includes the validator's *operational certificate*. The certificate is composed of the public portion of the operational key, certificate issue number, beginning KES period, and a cold key signature [as defined in the ledger spec](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/6173902/download/1/ledger-spec.pdf).

Once the new block is distributed to the network, each other validator can verify that the new block is valid, and that the publisher was eligible to forge a block in that slot.

All of this happens automatically as part of the `cardano-node` software. Operators only need to update their certificate periodically.

The proof of this distributed random selection process is a bit much for this answer, as is the proof for how the network selects a longest chain and handles soft forks, but worth reading up on if you're interested in this topic!

Comment: Thank you kindly for the detailed and easy to understand answer.